# std::bad_alloc on boost::archive::binary_iarchive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I have the above method which serialize a generic class.

```
std::unique_ptr<Message> Serializer::deserialize(char* data , int size) {
    std::stringstream ss(std::ios_base::in |
                           std::ios_base::out |
                           std::ios_base::binary);
    ss.write( data, size );
    Message *in;

    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss, boost::archive::no_header);
    ia >> in;
    return  std::unique_ptr<Message> (in);
}
```

I get

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

when I try to call deserialize on a char* that I am sure is sent integrally.
The class that I try to deserialize to can be found here:

```
class DiscoveryMessage : public Message {
public:

  DiscoveryMessage() {}

  DiscoveryMessage(int tcpPort);

  virtual ~DiscoveryMessage(){}

  friend class boost::serialization::access;

private:
  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int ) {
    // invoke serialization of base class (Message)
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Message>(*this);
    ar & mTcpReceivePort;
    ar & mIPAddr;
  }

  int mTcpReceivePort;
  std::string mIPAddr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really do deserialize the same type as you serialized.

Specifically I see you mixing in unique_ptr and derived classes. E.g. you cannot use the above code to deserialize `DiscoveryMessage*` or `boost::shared_ptr<Message>` etc.

Simple demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b475bdb76042b08)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

class DiscoveryMessage;
struct Message {
    virtual ~Message() {}

    virtual void do_print(std::ostream& os) const { os << "(base)"; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Message const& m) {
        m.do_print(os);
        return os;
    }

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int) {
        ar.template register_type<DiscoveryMessage>();
    }
};

class DiscoveryMessage : public Message {
  public:
    DiscoveryMessage() {}

    DiscoveryMessage(int tcpPort) : mTcpReceivePort(tcpPort) {}
    virtual void do_print(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "{" << mIPAddr << ":" << mTcpReceivePort << "}";
    }

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int) {
        // invoke serialization of base class (Message)
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Message>(*this);
        ar & mTcpReceivePort;
        ar & mIPAddr;
    }

    int mTcpReceivePort;
    std::string mIPAddr = "hello";
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Message)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(DiscoveryMessage)

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        Message * p = new DiscoveryMessage(42);
        oa << p;
    }

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        Message * p;
        ia >> p;
        std::cout << *p << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
{hello:42}
```